# regexp notation for pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, ant

I want to skip PMD violations for all files in packages following `**/dto/Q[A-Z]**` e.g. PMD violation must be skipped for `com.abc.foo.bar.dto.QResult.java` but not for `com.abc.foo.bar.dto.Question.java`

Can someone point to the regexp notation allowed in pom.xml? How can I achieve the above intended? Following is what I tried but didn't work -

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <analysisCache>true</analysisCache>
                    <!-- enable incremental analysis -->
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>*/dto/Q[A-Z]**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
 <exclude>*/dto/Q{matcher:[A-Z]}**</exclude>
```

(or ** at the beginning).